# Why is marker orient="auto" not working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I was trying to draw two lines with markers. The code works fine in IE and Firefox, but in Chrome, the marker just doesn't rotate automatically. I have added orient="auto" in the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
version="1.1"
id="svg"
x="0px"
y="0px"
width="1276.263px"
height="4300.399px"
viewBox="0 0 1276.263 4300.399"
enable-background="new 0 0 1276.263 4300.399"
xml:space="preserve"><metadata
 id="metadata993"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
     rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
       rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
 id="defs991"><marker
   orient="auto"
   refY="0.0"
   refX="0.0"
   id="Arrow2Mend"
   style="overflow:visible;"><path
     id="path4320"
     style="fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:0.625;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1"
     d="M 8.7185878,4.0337352 L -2.2072895,0.016013256 L 8.7185884,-4.0017078 C 6.9730900,-1.6296469 6.9831476,1.6157441 8.7185878,4.0337352 z "
     transform="scale(0.6) rotate(180) translate(0,0)" /></marker></defs>
     <g
 id="subpath-container" /><path
 style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Mend)"
 d="M 829.46676,422.03786 C 800.47569,434.92278 499.29067,1993.9982 499.29067,1993.9982"
 id="path5161" /><path
 style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;marker-end:url(#Arrow2Mend)"
 d="m 529.89236,1095.275 c -30.60169,70.867 70.86706,1003.4131 70.86706,1003.4131"
 id="path5277" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are degenerate i.e. you've written them as cubic beziers but the control points are co-located so they become straight lines.

Chrome should cope with this but doesn't, there's an [open bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450368) on this issue in the Chrome bug database.

In the meantime if you want to draw straight lines, use a straight line command such as L or l. Chrome will draw the markers orientated correctly then.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Robert! But with this bug in Chrome, currently is there any workaround to draw curves with marker orient="auto" functioning?

Comment: You're not actually drawing curves, if you were Chrome would work.